# Why does KeyEvent getRepeatCount always return 0?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to catch and print the key pressed by the user (if the user holds down the key I want to print the key just once). To do so I checked the Android docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent) and found the method getRepeatCount that should returns 0 the first time the key is pressed then a non-zero value is returned. The problem is that it always returns 0.

I created a new Android project (on Intellij IDEA) with en empty activity then I implemented onKeyDown method as follows:

```java
package com.soft.uret.testonkeydown;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.i("key pressed", event.getKeyCode() + " - " + event.getRepeatCount());
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

When I press and hold a key on my physical keyboard this is what I get:

```
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
I/key pressed: 31 - 0
```

As you can see getRepeatCount() returns always 0, why? What am I missing?